# How do I dynamically call API in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my first time trying to create a dynamic APi call for countries and its corresponding states and cites.

```
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [states, setStates] = useState([]);
  const [cities, setCities] = useState([]);


const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    let countryURL = "https://countryAPI"; 
    let statesURL = "https://statesAPI"; 
    let citiesURL = "https://citiesAPI"; 

    const requestOne = await Axios.get(countryURL);
    const requestTwo = await Axios.get(statesURL);
    const requestThree = await Axios.get(citiesURL);

    Axios.all([requestOne, requestTwo, requestThree]).then(
      Axios.spread((...responses) => {
        const responseOne = responses[0];
        const responseTwo = responses[1];
        const responseThree = responses[2];

        setCountries(responseOne.data.data);
        setStates(responseTwo.data.data);
        setCities(responseThree.data.data);
      })
    );
  }, [data.country, data.states]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchData]);
```

The above code is an idea of what I intend to implement by dynamically selecting a country, which fetches its states and selecting a state, fetches the corresponding cities. I a guide on how to implement the onChange method to dynamically handle this.

```
              <select 
               value={data.countries}
              //onChange={HandleChange1}
               
               >
                <option value="">Select Country</option>
                {countries.map((item, i) => (
                  <option key={i} value={item}>
                    {item}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </select>
          
            <div>
              <select 
                value={data.states}
                 //onChange = {handleChange2}
                 >
                <option value="">Select State</option>
                {states.map((item, i) => (
                  <option key={i} value={item}>
                    {item}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </select>
           </div>
          
              <div>
              <select 
              value={items.facility_name} 
               >
                <option value="">Select City</option>
                {cities.map((item, i) => (
                  <option key={i} value={item}>
                    {item}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </select>
           </div>
```

How do I implement the handleChange function so when a country is selected, the dropdown for states changes to list the states for that particular selected country...same with the cities, when a state is selected. please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of `useEffect` below is a sample code.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

const FetchList = () => {
  //Form Values
  const [country, setCountry] = useState("");
  const [state, setState] = useState("");

  //Data list
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [states, setStates] = useState([]);
  const [cities, setCities] = useState([]);

  const fetchCountries = useCallback(() => {
    //fetch
    return ["USA", "UK"];
  }, []);

  const fetchStates = useCallback(() => {
    //fetch
    if (country === "USA") {
      return ["California", "NewYork"];
    } else if (country === "UK") {
      return ["UK1", "UK2"];
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }, [country]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const countries = fetchCountries();
    console.log(countries);
    setCountries(countries);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const states = fetchStates();
    console.log(states);
    setStates(states);
  }, [country]);

  return (
    <div>
      <select
        value={country}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setCountry(e.target.value);
        }}
      >
        <option value="">Select Country</option>
        {countries.map((item, i) => (
          <option key={i} value={item}>
            {item}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>

      <div>
        <select
          value={state}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setState(e.target.value);
          }}
          //onChange = {handleChange2}
        >
          <option value="">Select State</option>
          {states.map((item, i) => (
            <option key={i} value={item}>
              {item}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>

      <div></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FetchList;
```